# iOS Option Popup - Similar to Cut/Copy/Paste

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, user-interface, popup

For an app I'm developing I need some popup options, similar to how Cut/Copy/Paste is displayed when selecting text in a UITextView or UIWebView.

However, I'm having trouble finding what this kind of popup is called. Is there a public API for them, or is it something that has to be implemented from scratch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class you want to look at is UIMenuController.

If memory serves, you will need to create an array of UIMenuItem instances to describe the custom actions, and add them to the UIMenuController singleton using 'setMenuItems:'.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. I knew it would be something simple, but it's one of those situations where it's difficult to find without knowing the exact name! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html) and [UIMenuItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIMenuItem_Class/Reference/MenuItem.html) is what you are looking for.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#samplecode/CopyPasteTile/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009040) you find also an example project by Apple that explains how to use them.