# How to create copying pop-up?

Tags: ios, menu, uitextfield

I want to create same popUp as shown in image. This popUp is default in iPhone, but if I want to make it custom with my own message, how can I create it?

[image: Here is the image. As u know this is by default in iPhone. But how can i create it by my own message in popUp]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cite from [iOS Option Popup - Similar to Cut/Copy/Paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957562/ios-option-popup-similar-to-cut-copy-paste)

[UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html) and [UIMenuItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIMenuItem_Class/Reference/MenuItem.html) is what you are looking for.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435) you find also an example project by Apple that explains how to use them.